Deep links won't open my app from Meta Messenger app
I'm trying to integrate deep linking. When I open the link in safari, whatsApp, telegram etc. It opens the app fine. Even when sending the test deep link from Meta's App Ads Helper it sends notification to facebook app on my device and when pressed on it, it opens the App correctly.
However when I send a url https://my-configured-web.com/deeplink/21 to Messenger app it just opens a web browser inside the Messenger app.
I have my apple-app-site-association configured correctly (I guess, since the links opens from other apps)
Would appreciate any help either from personal experience, links to similar issues or setup tutorials. Thank you!
